# git-svn: Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to sync my svn repository to git on a daily basis. After much reading, I was able to make this work by manually creating the following in my .git/config:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = svn+ssh://svn.myserver.com/project/trunk
fetch = apps/ios/project:refs/remotes/mirror/project
```

I then created a branch based on this code and pushed it to the git repo with:

```
git checkout -b mirror/project mirror/project
git svn rebase
git push
```

I was very happy until I thought I'd really make sure this actually worked by deleting the cloned repo from disk and cloning it again, then trying to push some updates from svn.

```
git clone git@myrepo.com:myproject
git checkout mirror/project
git svn rebase
```

This gives me the following error: `Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`

I've read the myriad posts on stackoverflow about this message, but I've yet to understand any of the solutions. Is it possible to explain in terms a git newbie could understand why git has chosen to forget all about my svn config?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269566/unable-to-determine-upstream-svn-information-from-head-history)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how a simple "git clone" could know about your svn upstream repo information.

You have stored the `svn-remote` in your `.git/config`. And that local config is not cloned when you are cloning a repo (as I mention in "[Is it possible to clone git config from remote location?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309)").

Unless you do a `git svn clone` or put again that `svn-remote` information in your repo, you won't have access to your initial information.

Comment: Ok, that just seems weird to me, but that's one mystery solved. How would I fix my local clone such that `git svn rebase` will work again?

Comment: @Tim if your local config as the `svn-remote` info (and use the right git version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3445081/6309), then don't forget that a `git svn rebase` needs a `git svn fetch` first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18563677/6309

Comment: thanks got it working. I didn't realize that I had to create a local branch from the svn fetch and then push that "over" my existing remote svn branch. I'm somewhat surprised that it just worked, but I guess some merge magic happened in the background.

Answer (score 4):

The following commands got my fresh clone re-connected to Subversion:

```
git svn init https://svn.myserver.com/project -s
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/trunk refs/remotes/origin/master
git svn rebase
```

It seems that updating the refs was the missing step.

Comment: Worked in our setup in order to reconnect an existing git svn repo with the svn repo.